# How to work with contenerized ( docker ) laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, docker, webpack, workflow

I am trying to wrap my head around workflow with docker images and laravel application.I have a couple of questions.

I am using `docker-compose` to setup my working environment.

**Directory Structure**

```
├── app
├── api-mock
├── docker-compose.yml
├── logs
├── mariadb
├── nginx
└── php-worker
```

Directories `app` and `api-mock` are github projects, they are respectivly laravel and lumen applications.

**Question 1**
*How to manage environmental variables in app directory?Should i create `.env` file using `Dockerfile` instructions and set for example database credentials?Or manage this manually.*

**Question 2**
*How should my workflow looks like when i am working on a front-end part of the application and i need to bundle my javascript code each time i change it?This also should be included in `Dockerfile` as instructions (turning on webpack `watch` mode).The same story is when im updating the php dependancies and managing it by composer.I have to rebuild images each time im making the changes to the application source files?I hope not.Is it done by volumes and managing this in host (my laptop)?I hope it make sense.*

Can you describe your workflow with contenerized web application when yours source code changes quite often? it doesnt have to be a laravel application.

Anyway Docker is great tool,i would like to implement the tool into my project.

Best regards,
Jan

Answer (score 2):

Huh, this is too complex to explain in some sentences here... To understand you have to know a lot about Docker and how it's working.

My best advice is to check the project called [laradock.io](http://laradock.io/). I've used it a lot and I really like it. Easy to understand, give it a try.

I'm sure that after some digging on its documentation and sources, looking at its ’.env’ file you will feel all your questions answered. To tell the truth, this was the project that made me understand Docker better than reading their own huge official documentation...

Comment: Thanks @ARS81 for your answer.Frankly i do know about laradock and i am using it as my working environment.I have set this project up based on laradock.But i can not wrap my head around workflow with `app` image.I would like to make docker automate as much things as possible.Do you have an experience how to use it with other developers?I mean how do you manage for example `.env` file, manualy or via `Dockerfile` instructions.I think that creating it in image instruction can be cumbersome due to rebuilding the image after each changes.

Comment: @JanCiołek I'm afraid I not really understand this. In my case I store my Laravel source files on my host operating system (Windows) versioned with `git` (not inside an image) so I don't need to rebuild any image when I change something. That folder can be accessed as a volume in any image I want. But I think this is the common way... Although I haven't used Docker since months so my my memories are vague... Sorry.

Comment: I find it strange,because its hard to find an example of `docker` with `docker-compose` wchich shows how to set up production and development environment.Thanks for input anyway!Cheers